# Calculus please tell me if I am right

Tags: calculus

$$
f(x) =
\begin{cases}
 x^2 &\text{for } x > 1 \\
 x-1 &\text{for } 0 < x \le 1 \\
 0 &\text{for } x \le 0
\end{cases}
$$
Then what is the value of $\lim_{x\to 0^-}f(x^2) +\lim_{x\to 1^+} \frac{f(x-1)}{x+2} $    ?

The answer key is $-4/3$  but when I try to solve this, I got $0$.

Am I right? Can anyone tell me please.

Comment: Please rewrite your title, which currently is vague, irrelevant, and will never help someone find this solution, even if they had the same problem in mind.

Comment: @BrightKittdech Please remember that you can choose an answer among the given if the OP is solved, more details here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 2):

Note that

$$\lim_{x\to 0^-}f(x^2)=\lim_{y\to 0^+}f(y)=-1$$

$$\lim_{x\to 1^+} \frac{f(x-1)}{x+2}=\lim_{y\to 0^+} \frac{f(y)}{3+y}=-\frac13$$

then

$$\lim_{x\to 0^-}f(x^2)+\lim_{x\to 1^+} \frac{f(x-1)}{x+2}=-1-\frac13=-\frac43$$

Comment: @AndrewLi f is not continuos, it holds because we are taking one side limits

Comment: An alternative way of looking at it:  If $-1 < x < 0$ then $1>x^2 > 0$ and $f(x^2) = x^2 - 1$.  So \lim_{x\to 0^-}f(x^2) = \lim_{x\to 0^-} (x^2 -1} = -1$.

Comment: @ChoF $\lim\limits_{x\to0^-}x^2=0^+$ and $f(x\to 0^+)=-1$

Comment: @gimusi $\lim\limits_{x\to0^-}x^2=0$ not $0^+$. There is no real number $0^+$.

Comment: @ChoF it's a short way, used for a comment, when $x\to0^-$ we have that $x^2\to 0$ from right, vizualize like a parabola, $x^2$ is strictly positive for $x\neq 0$

Comment: @gimusi You are right. $x^2\to0$ as $x\to0^-$. But $\lim\limits_{x\to0^-}x^2$ is still the real number $0$.

Comment: @ChoF ok now I get your point you are referring to the first solution! now I get your point of course, you are right, I fix! Thanks

Comment: @gimusi ChoF is right, it doesn't make sense. Although you *could* develop such a theory, it is definitely not adapted in an answer to someone who could not do this limit by themselves.

Comment: @gimusi Good. Your alternative solution was excellent.

Comment: @ChoF Thanks again to have pointed it out and sorry for the my misunderstanding on that!

Comment: @ArnaudMortier Yes of course! Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Consider this:

If $-1 < x < 0$ then $0 < x^2 < 1$ and $f(x^2) = x^2-1$ and $\lim_{x\to 0^-} f(x^2)=\lim_{x\to 0^-}x^2 -1 =-1$.

and if $1 < x < 2$ then $0 < x - 1< 2$ and $f(x-1) = x-1 -1 = x-2$ and $\frac {f(x-1)}{x + 2}=\frac {x-2}{x+2}$.  So $\lim_{x\to 1^+}\frac {f(x-1)}{x+2} =\lim_{x\to 1^+}\frac {x-2}{x+2} = -\frac 13$.

And so $\lim_{x\to 0^-} f(x^2)+ \lim_{x\to 1^+}\frac {f(x-1)}{x+2}  = -1 + (-\frac 13) = -\frac 43$.

.....

Your mistake was assuming $\lim_{x\to 0^-}$ would mean $\lim_{x^2\to 0^-}$ and $\lim_{x \to 1^+} $ would mean $\lim_{x-1 \to 1^+}$. (the second one when you think about it doesn't actually make any sense, and the first one is just wrong.)

In actuality $\lim_{x \to 0^-}$ means $\lim_{x^2 \to 0^+}$ and $\lim_{x\to 1^+}$ means $\lim_{x-1 \to 0^+}$.

....

Another way to explain your error:

Let $g_1(x) = x^2; g_2(x) = x -1; g_3(x) = 0$ and $f(x) =
\begin{cases}
 g_1(x) &\text{for } x > 1 \\
 g_2(x) &\text{for } 0 < x \le 1 \\
 g_3(x) &\text{for } x \le 0
\end{cases}$

You assumed that if $x < 0$ then $f(x^2) = g_3(x^2)$ and if $x > 1$ then $f(x-1) = g_1(x -1)$.

But $x < 0$ means $x^2 > 0$ and if $-1 < x < 0$ then $0 < x^2 < 1$ so $f(x^2) = g_2(x)$.  Likewise if $2 > x > 1$ then $0 < x - 1 < 1$ so $f(x-1) = g_2(x-1)$.

Comment: good alternative!